How to uninstall ag-grid-community
I am trying to uninstall ag-grid-community from my React project, and none of the numerous npm uninstall commands I've tried seem to have any effect.  I've tried a bunch of variations of
npm uninstall -g --force --save ag-grid-community
and the package is still in node_modules and package.json, and the old code that uses the package still works.  Help?  Thanks!

I do not know why it is not removing it from your package.json file. I just ran npm uninstall ag-grid-community in my project and it removed it from the package.json file just fine. You can always manually edit your package.json file and remove it that way. As for why it is not removed from node_modules, npm uninstall never does that. To clear unused packages from node_modules, you must run npm prune after uninstalling the packages. However, doing so will not remove packages that are required for other installed packages. For example, if you have ag-grid-community and ag-grid-react installed, and you uninstall ag-grid-community and then run npm prune, it will not remove ag-grid-community from node_modules as ag-grid-react depends on it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks, and sorry for the delayed response.  I finally circled back around to this.  I manually removed ag-grid-react from package.json and ran npm prune --force, and both ag-grid-react and ag-grid-community were removed from node_modules.  Thanks again.
